# Org Shape Create failure and misleading error - SFDX

Tags: salesforcedx, org-shape

So my DevHub and SourceOrg is the same. Trying to create a Org Shape. After running the sfdx force:org:shape:create -u <source org username/alias> command, my org shape is succesfully created. I get the 'Successfully created org shape for XXXXX' message.
However upon running the sfdx force:org:shape:list command, I get 'No org shape found'.
Quick SOQL on ShapeRepresentation object shows Status as ERROR. Nothing in the description
No issues with authentication. What might be the issue, any clue?

Comment: So basically this cannot be tried in Dev environments. it requires a special license type called Tenant License